# Dynamic Find Function - Looping through all sheets

Tags: vba, excel

and want to `.Find` text only on current sheet in loop

Having some issue with this one, I have code that is looping through each sheet in my workbook and splitting/saving as a unique workbook. I want to name each sheet per some specific info found only on that sheet. Currently my loop is working but the .Find I am using is only finding the text on the first sheet.

Is there a way to define what sheet to search within in the .Find code, thinking find next, but I really only want it to search within the current sheet per the loop. Thank you greatly for any tips you may lend!

P.S. unfortunately each sheet is spaced differently which is why I need it to be dynamic in the sense of searching for specific text.

```
Sub Splitbook()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim emplID As String
    Dim LastName As Variant
    Dim FirstName As Variant
    Dim I As Long
    Dim Time As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    I = 1

    For Each xWs In wb.Worksheets
        emplID = ""
        Cells.Find(What:="EmplID:", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        emplID = ActiveCell
        emplID = Right(emplID, 6)
        Sheets("Tracker").Range("A" & I) = emplID
        I = I + 1
        Time = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
        xWs.Copy
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\SplitIRs\" & emplID & " " & Time & ".xlsx"
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Sheets saved successfully on your desktop."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim rng As Range
For Each xWs In wb.Worksheets
    emplID = ""
    '/Search in the sheet and after first cell
    Set rng = xWs.Cells.Find(What:="EmplID:", After:=xWs.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    '/ Did we find something?
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        emplID = rng.Value
        emplID = Right(emplID, 6)
        Sheets("Tracker").Range("A" & I) = emplID


        I = I + 1

        Time = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
        xWs.Copy
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\SplitIRs\" & emplID & " " & Time & ".xlsx"
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    End If
    Next
```